# Lucene - Search where array contains integer field

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I have an array of integers and need to search Lucene index where a specific field value belongs to this array.

For now I'm just thinking to do something like this (not tested yet, just thoughts):

```
var arrayWithIds = int[] {501,828,2837,928,2882....};

var booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
foreach(var id in arrayWithIds)
{
  var subQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("Id",NumericUtils.IntToPrefixCoded(id)));
  booleanQuery.Add(subQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
}
```

... then I use `booleanQuery` to search

Is there any other way?

I'm using Lucene.net 2.9. Can't upgrade to newer version due to other dependencies.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you already have? I know you haven't done it yet, but you should write the actual code and see if it performs to your needs. Come to us when you have a question about what you have done.

Comment: #gunr2171 I was wondering if there is more efficient way. I don't know much about Lucene search engine as I just started working with it. Was wondering if there is a more straight forward way to pass array of values that we need to search for.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to change your numeric id field to a string field instead.  Looks like they don't really represent numeric fields, but rather just identifiers that happen to be numbers.  Just a guess though.  I don't like having to use `IntToPrefixCoded`, since it's intended to be used only internally, by Lucene (as such, if Lucene.Net ever gets up to Lucene 4.0, there were signficant, non-backwards-compliant changes to `NumericUtils` in that version).

The way you are constructing the query, though, is just fine.  If you passed a query like `id:(501 828 2837 928 2882)`, the QueryParser would produce the same thing.

Comment: Thank you #femto. Yes, I had a feeling that I need to change the index, so that Id is a string value.